# Ubuntu wallpapers contest

Tags: desktop-background, community

Where can I vote for wallpapers in the wallpaper contest?

*Are there any special requirements for being able to vote?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you have to win a contest yourself -

"The best of the community submissions (selected by a panel made up of previous release winners) will ship as part of the stock Ubuntu 14.10 desktop"

found at [the last contest](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/ubuntu-14-10-wallpaper-contest).

As to where, I'm guessing that's something you find out when you qualify - I don't know because I haven't :)